# Basic GUI calculator

Tags: java, beginner, calculator

I know there's loads of these out there but I thought I'd give it a shot. My mate made a calculator but he used a GUI Builder and I personally prefer typing my GUI's by hand.

I've finished my first year of university (moving on to my second year) and I'm studying BSc Artificial Intelligence and Robotics, I wanted to test my Java skills considering I finished like a month ago and wanted to see what I could remember.

I'm uploading the code here, for any advice as I'd like to type Java with the correct rules, regulations and 'good habits'.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Main extends JFrame
{
    private Interface anInterface = new Interface();
    private ImagePanel imagePanel = new ImagePanel();

    private String request = "";

    public Main()
    {
        imagePanel.add(anInterface);

        add(imagePanel);

        actions();

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setSize(225, 300);
        setTitle("Calculator");
        setResizable(false);
    }

    public void actions()
    {
        anInterface.calculatorButtons.zero.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String text = anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.getText();

                request += 0;

                anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.setText(text + 0);
            }
        });
        anInterface.calculatorButtons.one.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String text = anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.getText();

                request += 1;

                anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.setText(text + 1);
            }
        });
        anInterface.calculatorButtons.two.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String text = anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.getText();

                request += 2;

                anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.setText(text + 2);
            }
        });
        anInterface.calculatorButtons.three.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String text = anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.getText();

                request += 3;

                anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.setText(text + 3);
            }
        });
        anInterface.calculatorButtons.four.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String text = anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.getText();

                request += 4;

                anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.setText(text + 4);
            }
        });
        anInterface.calculatorButtons.five.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String text = anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.getText();

                request += 5;

                anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.setText(text + 5);
            }
        });
        anInterface.calculatorButtons.six.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String text = anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.getText();

                request += 6;

                anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.setText(text + 6);
            }
        });
        anInterface.calculatorButtons.seven.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String text = anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.getText();

                request += 7;

                anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.setText(text + 7);
            }
        });
        anInterface.calculatorButtons.eight.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String text = anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.getText();

                request += 8;

                anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.setText(text + 8);
            }
        });
        anInterface.calculatorButtons.nine.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String text = anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.getText();

                request += 9;

                anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.setText(text + 9);
            }
        });

        anInterface.calculatorButtons.dot.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String text = anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.getText();

                request += ".";

                anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.setText(text + ".");
            }
        });

        anInterface.calculatorButtons.plus.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String text = anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.getText();

                request += "+";

                anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.setText(text + "+");
            }
        });

        anInterface.calculatorButtons.divide.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String text = anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.getText();

                request += "/";

                anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.setText(text + "÷");
            }
        });

        anInterface.calculatorButtons.multiply.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String text = anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.getText();

                request += "*";

                anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.setText(text + "×");
            }
        });

        anInterface.calculatorButtons.minus.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String text = anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.getText();

                request += "-";

                anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.setText(text + "-");
            }
        });

        anInterface.calculatorButtons.ac.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                request = "";
                anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.setText("");
            }
        });

        anInterface.clearButton.equals.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try
                {
                    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
                    ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

                    String answer = engine.eval(request).toString();

                    anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.setText("" + answer);

                    request = answer;
                }
                catch(ScriptException | NullPointerException e1)
                {
                    anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.setText("ERROR");
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Main itf = new Main();
    }
}

class CalculatorButtons extends JPanel
{
    protected JButton zero;
    protected JButton one;
    protected JButton two;
    protected JButton three;
    protected JButton four;
    protected JButton five;
    protected JButton six;
    protected JButton seven;
    protected JButton eight;
    protected JButton nine;

    protected JButton dot;

    protected JButton plus;
    protected JButton divide;
    protected JButton multiply;
    protected JButton minus;
    protected JButton ac;

    public CalculatorButtons()
    {
        setOpaque(false);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        zero = new JButton("0");
        one = new JButton("1");
        two = new JButton("2");
        three = new JButton("3");
        four = new JButton("4");
        five = new JButton("5");
        six = new JButton("6");
        seven = new JButton("7");
        eight = new JButton("8");
        nine = new JButton("9");

        dot = new JButton(".");

        plus = new JButton("+");
        divide = new JButton("÷");
        multiply = new JButton("×");
        minus = new JButton("-");
        ac = new JButton("AC");

        JLabel space = new JLabel("                                    ");

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.ipadx = -20;

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 4;

        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        add(zero, gbc);

        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        add(dot, gbc);

        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        add(ac, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;

        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        add(one, gbc);

        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        add(two, gbc);

        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        add(three, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;

        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        add(four, gbc);

        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        add(five, gbc);

        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        add(six, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;

        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        add(seven, gbc);

        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        add(eight, gbc);

        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        add(nine, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        add(plus, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        add(divide, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        add(multiply, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        add(minus, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        add(space);
    }
}

class CalculatorScreen extends JPanel
{
    protected JTextArea results;
    protected JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public CalculatorScreen()
    {
        setOpaque(false);

        results = new JTextArea(5, 16);
        results.setEditable(false);
        results.setLineWrap(true);

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(results);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        add(scrollPane, gbc);
    }
}

class ClearButton extends JPanel
{
    protected JButton equals;

    public ClearButton()
    {
        setOpaque(false);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        equals = new JButton("=");

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.ipadx = 124;
        add(equals, gbc);
    }
}

class ImagePanel extends JPanel
{
    protected Image loginImage;

    public ImagePanel()
    {
        this.loginImage =
                new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Pics/CalcBackground.jpg")).getImage();

        Dimension size = new Dimension(loginImage.getWidth(null), loginImage.getHeight(null));
        setPreferredSize(size);
        setMinimumSize(size);
        setMaximumSize(size);
        setSize(size);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(loginImage, 0, 0, null);
    }
}

class Interface extends JPanel
{
    protected CalculatorScreen calculatorScreen = new CalculatorScreen();
    protected CalculatorButtons calculatorButtons = new CalculatorButtons();
    protected ClearButton clearButton = new ClearButton();

    Interface()
    {
        setOpaque(false);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        add(calculatorScreen, gbc);

        gbc.ipady = 0;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        add(calculatorButtons, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        add(clearButton, gbc);
    }
}
```

[image: Image of the Calculator]

The link for the background image of the calculator: [http://imgur.com/zZehZlX](https://imgur.com/zZehZlX)

So, I'm not sure if I'm a beginner? I class my self as a beginner as I have no idea what level of skill you stop being a beginner at. The code itself is in 6 different separate classes, I've been told previously on StackOverflow to submit my code in one file, so that's what I've done here.

I realise that I have a lot of actions for buttons when I could try to limit those and make it more reusable just not sure how.

Any help on improving my style of typing code would be helpful, and I appreciate every bit.

Thanks.

Comment: zero = new JButton("0");
        one = new JButton("1");

consider suing for loop from 0 to 9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Digits

> ```
>         anInterface.calculatorButtons.zero.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
>         {
>             @Override
>             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
>             {
>                 String text = anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.getText();
>
>                 request += 0;
>
>                 anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.setText(text + 0);
>             }
>         });
> ```

You could replace this whole thing with something like

```
    class DigitButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        private final int DIGIT;

        public DigitButtonListener(int digit) {
            this.DIGIT = digit;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String text = anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.getText();

            request += DIGIT;

            anInterface.calculatorScreen.results.setText(text + DIGIT);
        }

    }
```

which you'd use like

```
        anInterface.calculatorButtons.zero.addActionListener(new DigitButtonListener(0);
```

Obviously the latter is a lot less code for the ten digits.

Consider making `request` a `StringBuilder`.

Or consider making `request` a collection type.  Currently you enter an entire string and then parse it.  But you know exactly what operation you are doing when the button is pressed.  Then you forget that to put it in a string.  You probably don't want it to be a standard collection.  A custom class is probably better, as you are adding either a digit, a decimal point, or an operation.  The digits and decimal points are parts of a number.  The operation is something different.  So you want to accumulate digits until the number is finished by selecting an operation.

I haven't tried to run this.  It's possible that you'd have to pass `anInterface.calculatorScreen` and `request` as parameters to the constructor.  Note that that works better if `request` is mutable, e.g. a `StringBuilder` or collection.

#### Operations

You can do something similar with the operations.

```
        anInterface.calculatorButtons.plus.addActionListener(new DigitButtonListener("+");
```

or

```
        anInterface.calculatorButtons.plus.addActionListener(new DigitButtonListener(PLUS);
```

#### Naming

I find the name `ClearButton` confusing.  I would have expected that to be the AC button, but it's actually the equals sign.  And it doesn't clear; it replaces the formula with the answer.

#### `Main`

I'm not crazy about `Main` extending the `JFrame`.  I'd rather have something like `Calculator` extend the `JFrame`.  Then you could reuse `Calculator` in other programs.  Perhaps that is over-engineering for this specific problem, but it seems easy enough to do.  And it's a good habit to develop.

#### Beginner

More of a meta question, but you are welcome to call yourself a beginner as long as you want.  If you find that the responses are too beginner-oriented, you can always stop and leave the tag off your questions.  Some (not all) people will give different answers as a result.

Here you are more than welcome to break your code into parts if it makes sense.  In fact, you are encouraged to do so.  Stack Overflow wants small simple questions with straightforward answers.  If your question is complex, they want you to simplify it to just the essentials.  So each question represents just a small, narrow problem.

We do broad reviews of your code.  We want to see the actual code as it is in your IDE.  No simplifying or hiding.  Unless you have personal information in the code or code in a language other than English, you should be able to just copy and paste.